# What are the generating distributions in EM?

Tags: categorical-data, expectation-maximization

I have $N$ latent variables $Z$ and $K$ latent variables $X$.

$Z_n \sim \text{Cat}(\gamma^n_{1:6})$

$X_k \sim \text{Cat}(\theta^k_{1:6})$

These have categorical distributions for the outcomes ${1,2,3,4,5,6}$. All $X$ has $N$ unobserved outcomes, and all $Z$ has $K$ unobserved outcomes. We observe the sums.

That is, we observe:

$s_{1,1} = z_1 + x_1$,

$s_{1,2} = z_1 + x_2$,

...,

$s_{n,k} = z_n + x_{k-1}$

$s_{n,k} = z_n + x_k$

The mission is to apply EM to this to be able to find the $N+K$ cpds.

In the original EM-paper it is stated that the Q-term is a summation, or expectation over the generating distributions. Now the first question is how many generating distributions there are, or what the labels are. One idea I had was to let only $Z$ be the latent variable, since if I know it also know $X$. But one serious problem, in my head anyway, is that I think that they are all the combinations of assignment of Z $\{1,...,6\}^N$ which is exponential...

Anyone has any clarifying ideas of what to do or where I'm mistaken?